# Dividing large numbers in c++ using strings

Tags: c++, divider

I have to write program which divides 2 large numbers in c++, that cannot be hold in any other variables than strings (i guess).
Numbers are integers.

I wrote some code which uses my previous function to substract from numbers, but it didn't work with operations like 1000/1 or 1234567890/2 :/ 
Could you please give me some advices how can i make such a function?

Here's my codes:
(substraction from numbers)

```
string a=xa, b=xb, tmp_a = "", tmp_b = "", wynik = "", tmp_left_a, tmp_left_b, wynik_return, zamiana;
int dl_a = 0, dl_b = 0, pozyczka = 0, end_a = 0, end_b = 0, tmp_wynik = 0, left_a = 0, left_b = 0, test = 9,spr_a,spr_b;
bool wieksza = false;
string *wsk_a = &a;


dl_a = a.length();
dl_b = b.length();

if (dl_b > dl_a)
{
    wieksza = true;
    zamiana = a;
    a = b;
    b = zamiana;
}

if (dl_a == dl_b) 
{
    if (a == b)
        return "0"; 
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dl_a; i++)
        {
            tmp_a = a[i];
            tmp_b = b[i];
            spr_a = stoi(tmp_a);
            spr_b = stoi(tmp_b);

            if (spr_a != spr_b)
            {
                if (spr_a > spr_b)
                    break;
                if (spr_b > spr_a)
                {
                    wieksza = true;
                    zamiana = a;
                    a = b;
                    b = zamiana;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}



    dl_a = a.length();
    dl_b = b.length();
    int *wsk_dl = &dl_a;



    for (int i = dl_b - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        tmp_a = a[dl_a - 1];
        tmp_b = b[i];
        end_a = stoi(tmp_a);
        end_b = stoi(tmp_b);

        tmp_wynik = end_a - end_b;

        if (tmp_wynik < 0)
        {

            zamien(*wsk_a, dl_a - 2, *wsk_dl);

            tmp_wynik = (end_a + 10) - end_b;

            wynik += to_string(tmp_wynik);

        }
        else
        {

            wynik += to_string(tmp_wynik);

        }

        dl_a--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= dl_a - 1; i++)
    {
        tmp_a = a[i];
        wynik += tmp_a;
    }
    bool minus = false;
    for (int i = wynik.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (wieksza)
        {
            wynik_return += '-';
            wieksza = false;
            minus = true;
        }
        wynik_return += wynik[i];
    }

    if (minus)
    {
        while (wynik_return[1] == '0')
        {
            wynik_return.erase(1, 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (wynik_return[0] == '0' && (wynik_return[0] == '-' || wynik_return[0] != '-'))
        {
            wynik_return.erase(0, 1);
        }
    }

    return wynik_return;
```

}

Dividing function:(added one condition which test if b==1 to improve speed of program)

```
    string a=xa, b=xb, wynik;
long unsigned int tmp_wynik = 0;

while (a >= b || a.length() > b.length())
{
    if (a >= b && b.length() > a.length())
        break;
    if (b == "1")
        return a;
    a = odejmowanie(a, b);
    tmp_wynik++;
}
wynik = to_string(tmp_wynik);

return wynik;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], _Minimal_ being the keyword here.

Comment: How would you do such divisions using pen and paper? Try to translate that into an algorithm that can be put into code.

Comment: Here's the best "some advices" for you: you need to invest some time in learning how to effectively use your debugger. This will allow you to execute your program, one line at a time, and observe the values of all variables, as they change while the program executes, and follow your program's logic, step by step. This is what a debugger is for. Using your debugger you should be easily able to figure out your bugs, that's what it's there for. stackoverflow.com is not a remote debugging service. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries that can do this for you, like [this one](https://github.com/kasparsklavins/bigint).